# Random negative number when converting numbers from string to int in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

Attempting to convert string of numbers to binary with this code

```
public static int convert(String text)
{
    int num =0;
        for(int i =0; i<text.length();i++)
        {
            if(((int)text.charAt(i)>=48)&&((int)text.charAt(i)<=59))
            {
                System.out.println("Before: i = " + i + " num = "+ num+" char = "+ text.charAt(i) + "numchar = " + ((int)text.charAt(i)-48));
                num = num*10 + ((int)text.charAt(i)-48);
                System.out.println("After: i = " + i + " num = "+ num+" char = "+ text.charAt(i) + "numchar = " + ((int)text.charAt(i)-48));
            }

        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

However once it reaches its 10th number the output becomes a complete jumble with negative numbers and random numbers, even when my test strings are binary. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Could you share an example of input that leads to the error? Maybe your string representation does not fit into an int?

Comment: As an off-topic remark, I would suggest using character literals `'0'` and `'9'` instead of their ASCII values. Java will be happy to do addition and subtraction with these, since they are really just numbers.

Comment: in other words, `'0' == 48` and there is no need to cast `char` to `int` when doing calculation (not concatenation) - so you could write `... (text.charAt(i) - '0')` (same for `'9'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` datatype in Java is a 32-bit signed integer, so the maximum value it can represent is 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647. Since you are trying to parse numbers bigger than this, your arithmetic will result in [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

To solve this problem you will need to use a datatype which can represent larger integers, such as `long` (up to about 19 digits) or [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (arbitrarily large).